# I'm not able to permanently remove variable watches in Intellij?

Tags: variables, intellij-idea, watch

**Problem:** I am not able to permanently remove variable watches? I don't add them very often because they causing debugging "Collecting Data" issues. However, I have added and removed these many times in the past on this and other projects **but they just keep coming back**. Some variables don't even exist anymore and these checks still keep popping up.

**What I have tried:** I've tried what you are supposed to do, select them and remove them. Not sure what else to do. I have removed them and closed the project but opening the project and debugging causes them to come back.

[image: Variable Watches]

Comment: Is it reproducible with some sample project?

Comment: @y.bedrov - No.  Honestly, I hadn't noticed and didn't think to look at that possibility and probably should have. So I switched to an older project and added and removed variable watches and they seemed to clear fine. When I switched back to the project I was having an issue, I was able to permanently remove them. -- Thanks for the suggestion. I tried a number of things except and none seemed to work, so the project must have cleared/reset or done something. Again, thanks! If you can post an answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to switch to another project and return.

Comment: still not working.